# Nextjs Mongodb stream data on a serverless app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, backend

I am using these guides to create my Next-Mongo app without a NodeJS server:

https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/nextjs-with-mongodb/
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/build-nextjs-with-mongodb-and-deploy-on-vercel/#setting-up-the-api-route

I couldn't find the answer to this but is it possible to stream data? The closest solution I have to making the ap look real-time is either refreshing the page or getting back the published data on the response (which I can just append to the state) - this however is very limited.

I have used libraries like Pusher in the past with an express app but I can't use that on my serveless app.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The link you shared is anchoring "Add handler function"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me you want to watch and consume on the front end collection changes from your mongodb!? If so, I'd try ably for real-time communication.

- You can use ably in your model to broadcast the data you want to render real-time. You could also use pusher to accomplish the same result.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/change-streams.html